How to add a Custom Bottom in FROALA Editor to set opacity to 20% for the selected text
How to add a Custom Bottom in FROALA Editor to set opacity to 20% for the selected text.
I had several attempts but could not even add a button to the editor.
I`ve installed editor 4.2.0 via NPM in my nodejs project.
Here is my script insert in head section:
<script>
    $.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon("opacity",  {NAME: 'cog', SVG_KEY: 'cogs'});
    $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand("opacity",
        {
            title: "Opacity",
            focus: false,
            refreshAfterCallback: false,
            callback: function () {
                this.html.insert("<style=\"opacity: .2;\">" + this.html.getSelected() + "</style>");
            }
        }); 
</script>

And this is how I initialized the editor:
<script> 
    var editor = new FroalaEditor('#secttext', {
            enter: FroalaEditor.ENTER_BR,
            toolbarInline: false,
            toolbarButtons: ['undo', 'redo' , 'bold', 'underline', 'opacity'],
    });
</script>

